# Cannot find 'emulator.exe' when trying to test apps

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, temenos-quantum

I'm working with KonyOne Studio to build and test apps. The Android SDK is located in `C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk` and the emulator is located at `C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools\emulator.exe`. When I try to run apps, I get the error:

> Windows cannot find 'emulator.exe'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.

When I just run the emulator.exe executable, I get a quick cmd screen and it disappears as quick as it appeared. Nothing shows up in my task manager.

I've set the following environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
PATH: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32;D:\Users\SIMONSJP.GROUPINFRA\AppData\Roaming\npm;
      C:\KonyOne\ImageMagick;C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin;
      C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platform-tools;
```

Ofcourse the above is without spaces. I don't understand why the emulator doesn't run. Can anyone figure out why it isn't working?

Comment: Tried adding tools to path or copy emulator into platform-tools?

Comment: I don't know about the latter but adding tools to path worked! Thank you very much! You can write it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your path variable only includes platform-tools. It needs to include the path to the emulator too. 
Two ways:

- Copy the emulator.exe to platform-tools
- add the tools folder to path variable.

Answer (score 3):

Extract your sdk zip at some other place, copy tools directory, replace it with your actual sdk tools folder contents.

Restart eclipse if required...

This worked for me.Hope same happens with you too...